# using hadoop 2.2.0 jar files in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, hadoop

I was previously using hadoop 1.2.1 in one of my netbeans project. I did this by including the various jar files in the 1.2.1 distribution I downloaded from hadoop's website.

I was wondering, is a similar approach with hadoop 2.2.0 possible? Namely, can I just include a bunch of jar files in my netbeans project and plug into hadoop that way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can - There are more jars in the 2.x distributions of hadoop but the same principle should work.

On a side note, you may also want to look into using Maven for dependency management that will manage the list of included jars in Netbeans for you.

Comment: Thanks for the Maven tip--that saved a lot of digging around different folders for jar files.

However, I am now getting the warning for native libraries not being able to be loaded. Do you know a way I can fix that?

Comment: If you have a 2.2.0 installation you should be able to add the $HADOOP_HOME/lib/native path to your `java.library.path` or add this to the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable

Comment: I tried to use the command `-Djava.library.path=/home/victor/_ct/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native`, but I am still getting the same warning.